# next and toggle jquery. first function is executing whereas second is not,by default it is executing without any click

Tags: jquery, html

Why is my code not working on my system?

Although I have included toggle it vanishes when the document load.

Here is my JS code.

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $('.menu-content').hide();
            $('..menu-head').toggle(
                function() {
                    $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeIn();
                },
                function() {
                    $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeOut();
                });
        }); // end ready
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="menu-region">
            <div class="menu-head"><h4>Keyword</h4><i class="icon-join"></i></div>
            <div class="menu-content"><p>djakhskdjasdkjasdkjabsndkjabsdjhabsdjkhas</p></div>
            <div class="menu-head"><h4>Company </h4><i class="icon-join"></i></div>
            <div class="menu-content"><p>djakhskdjasdkjasdkjabsndkjabsdjhabsdjkhas</p></div>
            <div class="menu-head"><h4>Job title</h4><i class="icon-join"></i></div>
            <div class="menu-content"><p>djakhskdjasdkjasdkjabsndkjabsdjhabsdjkhas</p></div>
            <div class="menu-head"><h4>Education</h4><i class="icon-join"></i></div>
            <div class="menu-content"><p>djakhskdjasdkjasdkjabsndkjabsdjhabsdjkhas</p></div>
            <div class="menu-head last"><h4>Location</h4><i class="icon-join"></i></div>
            <div class="menu-content"><p>djakhskdjasdkjasdkjabsndkjabsdjhabsdjkhas</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `..menu-head` shouldn't this be only a `.menu-head`?

Comment: Also, [this form of toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: @Aravona yeah i corrected that even than i am facing the same problem :(

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ohh now i got it i was using that time older version thats why it was working well but now i am using letest jquery... :P
ohh fine fine got the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because some syntax error in your code. you used "..menu-head" instead ".menu-head"

```
 $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.menu-content').hide();
        $('.menu-head').toggle(
            function() {
                $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeIn();
            },
            function() {
                $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeOut();
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4Uv7K/1/)**
 try this ..i don't know what u are asking .one syntax error in class selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.menu-content').hide();
        $('.menu-head').toggle(

        function () {
            $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeIn();
        },

        function () {
            $(this).next('.menu-content').fadeOut();
        });

});
```